# Set spacing between two lines of text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to set spacing between two lines of text, but am not able to. Right now, the two lines are rendering after each other, but i want a bit of spacing between that i can adjust. I have tried using the `Spacer` widget but this makes the spacing too large. Is there a better way to do this?

```
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("We're finding your pizza.",
                  style: theme.textTheme.body1.copyWith(fontSize: 18)),
              Text(
                  "We'll send you a notification.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: theme.textTheme.body1.copyWith(fontSize: 18)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Use `SizedBox(height: 20)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Spacer` will take up all the available spaces left, and you may not need this. So you can simply use `SizedBox` widget.

```
Text("One"),
SizedBox(height: 20), // use this
Text("Two"),
```

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly. Now if i want this spacing to vary on screen size, would i be able to use "MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5"? I tried putting this in the sizedbox but it returned error. (I want to make sure that this height is less on smaller screens and larger on larger screens - i.e. it'll appear the same on all screens).

Comment: Yes, you can do that, can you edit your question with the full code which is causing the error?

Comment: just solved the error, just small syntax error. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also set a specific padding between text lines by setting the `height` property in the `TextStyle`. With this you set the height for each line.

```
                  Text(
                    "Let's make\nsome pancakes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1.2, //SETTING THIS CAN SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
```

In fact, we can confirm from the docs that:

> For most fonts, setting height to 1.0 is not the same as omitting or setting height to null because the fontSize sets the height of the EM-square, which is different than the font provided metrics for line height.

For more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html

I posted this same answer at [Flutter how do I remove unwanted padding from Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008822/flutter-how-do-i-remove-unwanted-padding-from-text-widget/66645804#66645804) to get the opposite result but it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the SizedBox widget or Container widget with padding.

SizedBox(height: 15.0)

or

Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0))