# flutter: how can make the text close to upper edge of the Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with flutter recently. When I layout the text, I usually put a `Text` into a `Container` and set the distance between `components`. My example code and the pictures will be below. However, I found the `Text` content wouldn't close to the edge, which makes the distance I set is not exactly accurate. So how should I solve the problem, or is there any better solution in my situation?
[image: the text content won't close to the edge]

```
Container(
           color: Colors.red,
           width: double.infinity,
           height: ScreenAdapt.heightToDp(32),
           child: Text(
             'some text content',
             style: MyTextStyle.level3
           ),
          ),
```

Comment: Because ```Text()``` widget has a default padding. Thats why its not exactly at the edge

Comment: Take a look at this question to read more about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008822/flutter-how-do-i-remove-unwanted-padding-from-text-widget

Answer (score 2):

In short, you shouldn't, the extra space is for the safety margin for other characters.

---

There are unsafe solutions, however. Be cautious. Use only if

1. You have explicitly declared the `fontFamily`.
2. You manually eyeballed that the font works on every platform (Specifically, Web).
3. You have fully decided it's completely OK to break other characters and other fonts.

If `TextStyle.height` is not null, then it will force the line height to be exactly `fontSize * height`. `fontSize` is the EM-square in typography. For typical fonts, their ascent and descent of latin characters USUALLY do not exceeds the height range of a EM-square. So setting `TextStyle.height` to something slightly larger than 1.0 USUALLY clip the line height without biting into the character.

See [Flutter's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html)

For Roboto, the sweet spot should be somewhere around 1.05~1.10 (Disclaimer: I am no font experts.)

[image]

Try this out

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Text(
    'asdfdsadfsadfasdf',
    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 50, height: 1.0)
  ),
),
```

As a last resort, you can always resort to something like a `OverflowBox` and either eyeball some values, or extract the metadata of the font and set the precise ascent and descent.