# Flutter: Adjust Text widget to parent without undesired font paddings

Tags: flutter, text, fonts, widget, padding

I'm trying to center both texts, and for the **T** text to take as much height as possible from the parent so the only space remaining will be the container's paddings.

**The code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Remove status bar
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _body(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _body() => Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Text("T"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Text("subtitle"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot there are undesired paddings in the **T** text:

[image: Text Widget undesired paddings]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008822/flutter-how-do-i-remove-unwanted-padding-from-text-widget

Comment: @Fatimaayaa I've already tried all the answers in there before posting the question, the checked one didn't worked for me since it requires magic numbers and a `Stack` which is not what I want, the custom `BaselineText`widget didn't work either, and the style and containers height try/error don't seem like a nice solution at all, also couldn't make it work in this example with the default font.